# C++ - Play multiple Beeps simultaneously via multi-threading?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, beep

Is it possible to play 2 or more beeps (from windows.h) simultaneously? I am very inexperienced when it comes to multi-threading but shouldn't the following do the job?

```
#include <thread>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void operation1();
void operation2();

int main()
{
    thread task1 = thread(operation1);
    thread task2 = thread(operation2);
    task2.join();
    task1.join();

    return 0;
}

void operation1()
{
    Beep(523, 1000);
}

void operation2()
{
    Beep(262, 1000);
}
```

When I compile and run this the program only plays a beep with a frequency of 262 Hz. Does that mean, that only operation 2 is called or are the two sounds somehow still blocking each other?

Comment: Your program will terminate immediately because you're not waiting for the threads to finish. You need to call `join()` on them to wait for them to complete before returning from your main function.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, it should actually crash. I wonder if Lukas is paying any attention to his program behaviour.

Comment: Oh yes, I'm sorry. I do actually call join() in my program. For some reason I didn't copy it though.

Comment: What else is different between your actual code and the code you posted?

Comment: I see no evidence that you can expect both sounds to be played simultaneously. Beep is an ancient legacy function. Don't use it. What are you trying to do and why did you decide Beep was the solution?

Comment: I was gonna write a program that plays "Take no Prisoners" by Megadeth. I just wanted to hear what that would sound like ^^. Are there any modern alternatives?

Comment: Oh yeah, the code is now an exact copy out of my editor.

Answer (score 2):

The `Beep` method is actually came from dinosaur era, when PCs had internal speakers.
Guess what? The internal speaker could play only one sound of one frequency at a time.
Nowadays, Windows just simulate that behavior, so that nothing in the system can make Windows play 2 or more BEEPS at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Your code exposes a problem I see very often (usually better hidden, though), which produces unexpected results and leaves the developers hairless. Namely, you fail to take into account lifetime of your threads.

When you start a new thread (no matter how, say, using C++11 `std::thread`) the starter thread continues executing (in your case, `main()`). Unless you ask for it, starter thread does not wait for anything to happen to the thread it just started. It just moves on, and than `main()` returns, and by definition, it means your program stops executing. Nobody gurantees you that the threads you've started had any chance to perform any operation at all!

You need to make a habit of waiting for threads to finish before returning from main - for example, by using `thread::join`. Actually, c++11 `thread` class will abort the program in it's destructor unless the thread was either joined, or detached - but I consider detached threads to be a of a bad design choice.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Funny thing: I somehow missed the two lines: task2.join(); and task1.join() when copying my code to this page. But even with those commands in place, I can still only hear one Beep.